# Testing on a physical device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having a problem with XCode and the ability to test an app on a physical device. I am running XCode v. 4.5.2 and my iPhone is OS 6.1. When I try to test on the physical device I get the following error:

"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

The deployment target for the app is 6.0. I don't know what else to check. Can anybody offer advice?

Thx!

Comment: Your Xcode is not supported for iOS 6.1 and your device is 6.1 :)

Comment: You are a paying developer and have set up all your provisioning profiles and such right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Xcode 4.6, which supports iOS 6.1 and above

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html

Comment: I just upgraded to 4.6.1 and am getting the same message. Any other ideas?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Mac OS, which I believe is 10.8.3